# Reading binary numbers from console

Tags: java, binary

How to read binary numbers from console and storing them in java, apart from `BigInteger`.

Edit: I need to read upto 2000 bits then do multiple operations like shift, or, and etc. and **I need a way other than `BigInteger`**
I dont want to use biginteger because i cannot get a bit at a particular index easily(though it has testBit() its not useful for me, as i need to print 1 or 0, this method returns true/false. Again an if-else is overhead). So i wanted to implement my own method of get.

Comment: Explain what you mean by "binary" numbers, since all numbers are binary... Do you mean to allow the user input a number in **binary format**, like "111"?

Comment: yes. I need to read numbers like 1100011, 1110001010101, etc.

Comment: How do you want to store them?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409998/store-binary-sequence-in-byte-array

Comment: `BigInteger` (and `java.math` in general) was created, amongst other things, for this use cases and is probably your best solution. Why do you want another way instead, any specific reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, maybe you could use `BitSet`

```
    String input="1001010101010101";
    int len=input.length();
    BitSet bs=new BitSet(len);
    int i=len-1;
    for (char c:input.toCharArray()) 
          bs.set(i--, c=='1'?true:false);
```

It supports logical operations, **but not shifts**

Edit: I also do not understand why not to use `BigInteger` as you failed to explain it...

Edit: changed code as previous version reversed bit order, which may be confusing

Answer (score 3):

```
Integer.parseInt(enteredString, 2);
```

Comment: Wont it throw a number format exception? Because wen i tried to parse a string or length 100+, it did. Pls check.

Comment: You originally didn't specify that you need to read numbers this long. See wmz's answer for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Read them as `Strings` and store them as `ints` using `Integer.parseInt(binaryString, 2);`. 
If you want the binary again, just use `Integer.toBinaryString();`

Comment: What do you mean if there are more bits?

Comment: yes. I tried to parse a string of 100+ length, it gave me a numberformatexception.

Answer (score 0):

Integer.parseInt(urString,2) can be used.

[Integer.parseInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

Comment: This wont help me if there are large number of bits, say above 100 or 200. This throws numberformatexception