# How to convert efficiently binary string to binary byte array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, binary-data

As an input I have binary string `String a = "100110"`. As output I need to have binary byte array `byte[] b = {1,0,0,1,1,0}`. 
For now I'm using

`for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
   b[i]= Byte.parseByte(a.substring(i, i+1));
}`

But this approach is too slow. Can any one give a better suggestion? Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Store binary sequence in byte array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409998/store-binary-sequence-in-byte-array)

Comment: @Nivas I don't think it's a duplicate, because it looks like OP wants to split each bit in its own byte.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727310/convert-binary-string-to-byte-array

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it without making objects for substrings, like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
    b[i]= a.charAt(i)=='1' ? (byte)1 : (byte)0;
}
```

The reason your approach is slower is that each call to `substring` produces a new `String` object, which becomes eligible for garbage collection as soon as `parseByte` is done with it.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the input is valid...

```
    byte[] b = new byte[a.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        b[i] = (byte) (a.charAt(i) - '0');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Makes an `int[]` instead of `byte[]` but I hope for points for elegance:

```
    int[] a = "100110"
            // Turn it into a stream.
            .chars()
            // Make '0'/'1' into 0/1
            .map(c -> c - '0')
            // Roll it into an array.
            .toArray();
```